# Cucumber rake task fails, blames JSON parser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rake, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a small Rails 4.0.0 / Ruby 2.0.0-p247 app for which I'd like to write some tests.  When I run

```
rake cucumber:all
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': uninitialized constant JSON::Parser (NameError)
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/multi_json-1.7.8/lib/multi_json/adapters/json_common.rb:16:in `load'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/multi_json-1.7.8/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:19:in `load'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/multi_json-1.7.8/lib/multi_json.rb:118:in `load'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/gherkin-2.12.0/lib/gherkin/i18n.rb:14:in `<class:I18n>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/gherkin-2.12.0/lib/gherkin/i18n.rb:6:in `<module:Gherkin>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/gherkin-2.12.0/lib/gherkin/i18n.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/gherkin-2.12.0/lib/gherkin/lexer/i18n_lexer.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/gherkin-2.12.0/lib/gherkin/lexer/i18n_lexer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/gherkin-2.12.0/lib/gherkin.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/gherkin-2.12.0/lib/gherkin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/cucumber:11:in `require'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/cucumber:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I've run bundle install, bundle update, gem cleanup, etc., to no avail.  This same Rails app runs fine on a different machine (Mac OS X 10.8.4), but mine (Mac OS X 10.8.2) does not work.  Any ideas?

Comment: what are the contents of your Gemfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have exactly the same error. The reason is here:

https://github.com/intridea/multi_json/issues/131

Since they have a bug fix, All you need to do is updating multi_json to 1.7.9

--edited Please do NOT change Gemfile.lock, check comments for detail

Comment: This will do it, but please don't ever update your Gemfile.lock by hand. Instead run `$ bundle update multi_json`.

Comment: Good point, Since, when you update a gem using `bundle update`, bundler will update all dependencies of that gem, including those that are also dependencies of another gem.

What if, multi_json-1.7.9 fixed the problem, multi_json-1.7.10 has that bug again?

Comment: In that case you would add `gem 'multi_json', '1.7.9'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle update multi_json` again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the source of the problem is not from the JSON::Parser. The 'ruby_noexec_wrapper' error could be suggesting a RVM problem.

Try

```
which cucumber
```

it should be aliased to bundled_cucumber

Also try updating RVM

```
rvm get stable
```

and/or making a fresh gemset

```
rvm gemset empty
```